# Determining which control has the focus on a .net form

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, code-behind

I've looked through a bunch of questions here, none seems to answer my specific one with my specific software.

Right now, when I tab from one text box to the next, the cursor *sometimes* ends up in points unknown.  Not all the time, but sometimes.  I know I have a few hidden fields on my form, and they are conditionally hidden.  Very complex, not easy to just edit it all out.

What I'd like to do is to see if I can figure out where this cursor goes when it disappears.  I have created an OnLeave function for a specific textbox (which gets fired by the OnTextChanged event on the front end/asp side), and at the conclusion of that function the cursor will not always end up in the same textbox.  I can't seem to find any methods or code that works for VS2012, or at least none that work with the Namespaces I'm currently using.

Comment: `HasFocus()` or can you look at your Tab Indexes for the controls and make sure that they are set up in the correct order..? as far as trying to figure out where the cursor goes.. can you not visually see where it's at ..?

Comment: Did you consider using javascript, handling the 'onblur' event?

Comment: I can't see where it's at, I'm surmising it's in one of the hidden fields although I don't know why it'd be there.  That's why I need to know where it's going!  Tabs are set up so that it *should* always end up in the proper textbox, but sometimes it just looks like nothing has the focus and when you start typing it doesn't show up anywhere.  You have to click inside the box to give it the focus, and my users are getting annoyed.  As am I.  ;o)

Comment: @CapitanCavernícola - I can't find any difference between OnTextChanged and OnBlur, and I'm already using OnTextChanged.  The text **must** change, it's an Acct# field, so OnBlur wouldn't add anything to it.  Unless I'm misunderstanding the difference?